# How to calculate single-name bond price using QuantLib?

Tags: c++, quantlib

I want to calculate the price of a bond, with discount factors known as a function of time, and fixed coupon.

The example I found (bond.cpp) from QuantLib 1.5 looks quite complicated. I deleted the zero-bond and floating coupon bond, leaving only the fixed coupon bond calculation part.

The part I don't understand is that how should I define RATE HELPERS and CURVE BUILDING parts, based on the table I have:

Instrument Typ     |    Maturity Date  |  Quote  |  Discount Factor

```
 CD                 03/04/2015       0.25        0.9999
 CD                 03/18/2015       0.254       0.9998
 CD                 06/17/2015       0.266       0.9997
 CD                 09/16/2015       0.38        0.9996
 CD                 12/16/2015       0.57        0.9995
.....
 SWAP               03/04/2019       1.33        0.94
 SWAP               03/04/2020       1.66        0.92
 SWAP               03/04/2021       1.74        0.89
```

What should I do to build the discount curve in QuantLib?

Answer (score 2):

You should use your discount factors directly and forget about rate helpers and curve building.

The latter are used when you want to imply a curve from some quoted price; but if you have already calculated the discount factors, you can just use the `InterpolatedDiscountCurve` class template and build the curve directly, as in:

```
#include <ql/termstructures/yield/discountcurve.hpp>

...

boost::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure> discountCurve(
    new InterpolatedDiscountCurve<LogLinear>(dates, discounts,
                                             dayCounter));
```

where `dates` is a `vector<Date>` (which must include as first date the start of the curve, usually today's date), `discounts` is a `vector<double>` containing the corresponding discount factors (including 1 as the first) and `dayCounter` will be used to convert dates into times; `Actual360()` should be ok.

The example above uses log-linear interpolation; you can change it by replacing `LogLinear` with a different one (look into the `<ql/math/interpolations/>` folder for the available ones).